# Laravel API + Sanctum + Angular + SSO (SAML) - How to build a Laravel 7/8 API with front-end in Angular 11 and SAML auth

Tags: php, angular, laravel, single-sign-on, saml

I need to turn my `laravel api + angular` `sanctum` authentication into a SAML authentication.

I've noticed that I need to use a laravel plugin like [laravel-saml2](https://github.com/24Slides/laravel-saml2) or [laravel-saml2](https://github.com/aacotroneo/laravel-saml2). (Yes... Same name but different plugins)

I intend to use [OKTA](https://www.okta.com/) because I am already using it to authenticate in my Stack ELK.

But my biggest doubt is: Since my front-end (`angular`) is communicating to my backend through a stateless `API` (`sanctum`), is it possible to implement a `SSO SAML` to authentication?

I would truly appreciate if anyone could show me how it is possible. And in case it is not, how could my app be rethinked to achieve this goal.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the right place to ask this question. I'm sure you'll get a good enough response on [r/laravel](https://www.reddit.com/r/laravel/) or [Laracast](https://laracasts.com/discuss).

Answer (score 1):

i had the same requirement working according to the next:

1. Laravel 8 with sanctum (the key to make use of SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS)

Make sure your Angular URL application is configured in SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS (.env)

like

```
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=localhost:4200
```

2. laravel-saml2 (https://github.com/aacotroneo/laravel-saml2) configured accorded to documentation.
3. In app/Http/Kernel.php

   ```
   protected $middlewareGroups = [
   'web' => [
       \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
       \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
       \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
       // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
       \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
       \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
       \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
   ],

   'api' => [
       \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
       'throttle:api',
       \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
   ],

   'saml' => [
       \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
       \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
       \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
   ],
   ```

   ];

And

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
    'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'password.confirm' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword::class,
    'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
// Add SAML Middleware
    'auth.saml' => \App\Http\Middleware\SAMLAuthenticated::class,
];
```

4. In app/Providers/EventServiceProvider.php

   ```
   namespace App\Providers;

   use Aacotroneo\Saml2\Events\Saml2LoginEvent;
   use App\Models\User;
   use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;
   use Illuminate\Auth\Listeners\SendEmailVerificationNotification;
   use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\EventServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
   use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
   use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event;
   use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
   use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;

   class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
   {
       /**
        * The event listener mappings for the application.
        *
        * @var array
        */
       protected $listen = [
           Registered::class => [
               SendEmailVerificationNotification::class,
           ],
       ];

       /**
        * Register any events for your application.
        *
        * @return void
        */
       public function boot()
       {
           Event::listen('Aacotroneo\Saml2\Events\Saml2LogoutEvent', function ($event) {
               Auth::logout();
               Session::save();
           });

           Event::listen('Aacotroneo\Saml2\Events\Saml2LoginEvent', function (Saml2LoginEvent $event) {
               $messageId = $event->getSaml2Auth()->getLastMessageId();
               // Add your own code preventing reuse of a $messageId to stop replay attacks

               $user = $event->getSaml2User();
               $userData = [
                   'id' => $user->getUserId(),
                   'attributes' => $user->getAttributes(),
                   'assertion' => $user->getRawSamlAssertion()
               ];

               //If it not exists, create a Laravel User from an Authenticated SAML account
               $laravelUser = User::firstOrCreate([
                   'email' => $user->getAttribute("urn:oid:0.9.2342.19200300.100.1.3")[0],
                   'name' => $user->getAttribute("urn:oid:0.9.2342.19200300.100.1.1")[0],
               ], ['password' => Hash::make('CREATE_DUMMY_NOT_BEING_USED')]);

               Auth::login($laravelUser); // AUTHENTICATION WITHIN LARAVEL
           });
       }
   }
   ```
5. Next, I've created a new Middleware (/app/Http/Middleware/SAMLAuthenticated.php)

   ```
   namespace App\Http\Middleware;

   use Aacotroneo\Saml2\Saml2Auth;
   use Closure;
   use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

   class SAMLAuthenticated
   {
       /**
        * Handle an incoming request.
        *
        * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
        * @param  \Closure  $next
        * @param  string|null  ...$guards
        * @return mixed
        */
       public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$guards)
       {
           if (!Auth::check())
           {
               if ($request->ajax())
               {
                   return response('Unauthorized.', 401); // Or, return a response that causes client side js to redirect to '/routesPrefix/myIdp1/login'
               }
               else
               {
                   // VERY IMPORTANT WHEN ANGULAR REQUEST
                   $retUrl = 'http://localhost:4200';
                   $saml2Auth = new Saml2Auth(Saml2Auth::loadOneLoginAuthFromIpdConfig('corsisa'));
                   return $saml2Auth->login($retUrl);
               }
           }
           return $next($request);
       }
   }
   ```
6. You can test SAML Auth (/app/routes/web.php)

   ```
   Route::middleware('auth.saml')->group(function () {
     //protected routes go here
     Route::get('/', function () {
           return view('welcome');
       });
   });

   // Also, you can map login & logout
   Route::redirect('/login', '/saml2/<idp_name>/login')->name('login');
   Route::redirect('/logout', '/saml2/<idp_name>/logout')->name('logout');
   ```

At this point, laravel application should redirect to SAML2 Login page.

7. Configure API routes, (app/routes/api.php:)

   ```
   Route::middleware('auth.saml')->group(function () {
       // Secured routes go here
       Route::get('/me' ,function (Request $request) { return $request->user(); });
       Route::get('/login' ,function (Request $request) {
           return redirect('http://localhost:4200');
       });
   });
   ```
8. In Angular application, I use the next steps:

First, Make an HTTP Request to "http://laravel_api/api/me"

For example:

```
this.http.get<User>(URLHelper.concat(environment.API_BASE_URL, "api", "me"), { withCredentials: true, setHeaders: {"X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"} })
```

If response is 401, (UNAUTHORIZED), then will be redirected to "http://laravel_api/api/login"

```
window.location.replace(URLHelper.concat(environment.API_BASE_URL, "api", "login"), { withCredentials: true, setHeaders: {"X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"} })
```

Redirection will send the user to the SAML2 Login Page and then redirect back to Angular frontend. (by SAMLAuthenticated middleware )

So when redirect back is completed, Angular makes a new request to http://laravel_api/api/me, this time with an Auth Cookie generated by Sanctum.

Surely this procedure can be improved, but you can use it as a working starting point.

Regards